# Word meaning 'distance from the center'

Tags: single-word-requests

I wonder if there is a word meaning 'distance from the center' of a circle or any other randomly shaped figure.

Radius is the distance from the center to the edge (of a circle), so it is not the answer I am looking for.

In this image, https://www.cut-the-knot.org/m/Geometry/TwoDotsInCircle.shtml
One dot is at the center and the other is not.
I wonder if there is a term meaning the distance between these two dots.

Comment: I don't think there's a word for it.

Comment: You could refer to the ***offset*** from the centre.

Comment: A circle doesn't have an edge, so no. And the correct term *is* radius whether you are looking for it or not.

Comment: The fact that there's a circle drawn around the two dots is irrelevant to their relationship - they're just two dots ***some arbitrary distance apart***. The circle only comes into play because its circumference represents some *other* length (not *shape*), that the puzzle-maker invites you to divide up in different ways to achieve some particular spatial arrangement.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking us to name something that can't really even be *defined*

Answer (score 2):

I would call it ***radial distance***. I don't think I know a one-word term for it.

The Cambridge Dictionary has [an entry](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/example/english/radial-distance) for this particular collocation. It doesn't include a definition but rather points you to the individual words.

> **radial:** spreading out from a central point
> **distance:** the amount of space between two places

It does include some examples of use that seem to fit your description:

> The radial distance is given from the crater centre.
> The radial distance to the fovea was defined as retinal eccentricity.
> The points were located at an equal radial distance from the center of the chemical releaser (30 cm)

And the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) on spherical coordinates consistently refers to them to as radial distance, azimuthal angle, and polar angle.

Some excerpts:

> In mathematics, a spherical coordinate system is a coordinate system for three-dimensional space where the position of a point is specified by three numbers: the *radial distance* of that point from a fixed origin, its *polar angle* measured from a fixed zenith direction, and the *azimuthal angle* of its orthogonal projection on a reference plane that passes through the origin and is orthogonal to the zenith, measured from a fixed reference direction on that plane.
> [...]
> This article will use the ISO convention frequently encountered in physics: (*r, θ, φ*) gives the radial distance, polar angle, and azimuthal angle.

Comment: Could you quote the sources in case the links break? (Also future visitors won't have to click through them)

Comment: Done, thank you. My edit seemingly clashed with someone else's, so I tried to also incorporate their reformatting of the links.

Answer (score -1):

> Radius is the distance from the center to the edge (of a circle), so
> it is not the answer I am looking for.

A circle does not have an edge. It is a one-dimensional object in a higher-dimensional space. The radius points to it. Same with a sphere (2D object in 3D space). For objects that have a non-zero radial dimension, *radius* is the correct term, and by itself it does not refer to any boundary dimension. You can trigger the more general sense of radius by saying "disc" or "spherical solid", and using "outer radius" consistently when you need to refer to the boundary radius.

In your linked example it says -

> In addition to the center of a circle another dot is marked within. Cut the circle into at most three parts such that, by rearranging the pieces, you get a circle with the center at the dot.

The problem is entirely with the way the question is worded. You don't have to cut the circle, just slide it. The dots are not part of the circle. If they had said *disc*, then the idea of an arbitrary radius is perfectly obvious.

Comment: I don't see how this question helps. The word he's looking for isn't the distance from the center to the circle, it's from the center to the other point inside the circle.

Comment: It's a frame challenge, pure and simple.

Comment: @Barmar: I'm not convinced it's relevant that the "amount of string" in the original "container" should be a circle with one dot at its centre. The string could just as well have been laid out as a square or just a random shape.